# How to get and passed JSON Array using Android volley?

Tags: php, android, arrays, json, android-volley

I'm having a problem in Android Studio on how to intent JSON Array using Android Volley String Request.

My goal is whenever user enter correct login and password. it will bring along other value of that particular user which is in my case is **realname** and **dept**.

I have these JSON Array output

```
{
    "login":"ID001",
    "realname":"Tom",
    "dept":"ICTD"
}
```

Produce by this PHP code below

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    $conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");

    if(
        isset($_POST['login']) &&
        isset($_POST['password'])
    ){
        $login = $_POST['login'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$login' AND pw = '$password' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $logindb     = $row['login'];
                $realnamedb  = $row['realname'];
                $deptdb      = $row['dept'];
                echo "success_login";
                $response = array('login' => $logindb, 'real_name' => $real_namedb, 'dept' => $deptdb);
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        mysqli_free_result($result);
        } else {
            echo "login_failed";
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Login :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="login"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In Android Studio, my current problem is the JSON Array can't be display inside **try{}** .

**LoginActivity.java**

```
  public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText etLogin, etPassword;
    Button bLogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        etLogin         = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etLogin);
        etPassword      = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        bLogin          = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = "http://localhost/login.php";
                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(response.equals("success_login")){
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject   = new JSONObject(response);
                                JSONArray booking       = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                                if(booking.length() > 0){
                                    for (int countItem = 0; countItem<booking.length(); countItem++){

                                        JSONObject bookingObject    = booking.getJSONObject(countItem);
                                        final String login                 = bookingObject.isNull("login");
                                        final String realname              = bookingObject.isNull("realname");
                                        final String dept                  = bookingObject.isNull("dept");


                                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("login", login);
                                        intent.putExtra("realname", realname);
                                        intent.putExtra("dept", dept);
                                        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                    }
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        } else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }){
                    @Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                        params.put("login", etLogin.getText().toString());
                        params.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
                        return params;
                    }
                };
                MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Appreciate if someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: Is above giving json output your whole json output? Or is it a part?

Comment: @R.R.M , output as above . it is not a part .

Comment: If that is so, It will not go even inside if condition of your code where you have written response.equals("success_login").

Comment: @R.R.M, but my php code already echo "success_login" . how to display the other json output ?

Comment: Can you log that response string after getting response and let me know what is its output? I m not getting your exact output.

Comment: @R.R.M, my Log can show string response "success_login" because in my php code I echo "success_login"

Comment: So from where are you getting {
    "login":"ID001",
    "realname":"Tom",
    "dept":"ICTD"
} this response?

Comment: @R.R.M . . Those value is from my mysql database  . . Table users . .

Comment: You are confused with response. Be sure about that. How will we provide answer if you yourself are confused?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get **JSON object** like this

---

```
  String url = "http://localhost/login.php";
            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                         Log.e("response>>>>","",response);
                    if(response.equals("success_login")){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject   = new JSONObject(response);



                                    final String login                 = jsonObject.getString("login");
                                    final String realname              = jsonObject.getString("realname");
                                    final String dept                  = jsonObject.getString("dept");


                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
                                    intent.putExtra("login", login);
                                    intent.putExtra("realname", realname);
                                    intent.putExtra("dept", dept);
                                    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                    params.put("login", etLogin.getText().toString());
                    params.put("password", etPassword.getText().toString());
                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
        }
```

Comment: It didnt work . . I can't show Log.d(TAG, "JSON Object" + jsonObject);

Comment: can you provide me,Logcat,  Log.d(TAG, "response>>>>" + response);
use this in OnResponse

Comment: It didnt show any value on my log . . It think string response it conflict with the jsonobject . .

Comment: nopes it does not relate with this, please Rozaimi paste this under OnResponse Log.d(TAG, "response>>>>" + response); and provide me valuable logcat  like this now i am editing my answer

Comment: And Response can print out the JSON Object in logcat . . it shows "Response is =success_login{"login":"PNM0273","real_name":"ID001 TOM","dept":"ICTD"}"

Comment: But it cannot intent into next activity

Comment: Replace this(where you pass the intent)--->>    LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
 with This------->>   startActivity(intent);

Comment: I think i found the answer . I change response.equals("success_login") into response.contains("success_login"). and I have to assign response as JSON first before I can pass it into JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);

Comment: Btw. Thanks for the feedback . god bless you . :)